# representing calendar events

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

Is there any .Net class that I can use to represent Calendar events which covers both:

- Single time events (e.g. Thursday August 21st at 8pm)
- Recurring events (e.g. each Monday at 9am or April 1st each year)

Comment: Use Noda Time.  (although it alone may not be enough)